# batch Google contact in dotnet

Tags: google-contacts-api

I cannot find any sample for batching contact insertions in dotnet.
We're using nuget package :  Install-Package Google.GData.Contacts

For appointments we're batching in this way:

```
BatchRequest batch = new BatchRequest(service);
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource.InsertRequest ir = new EventsResource.InsertRequest(aservice, theEvent, userName);
batch.Queue<Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event>(ir,
                       ( error, i, message) =>
                       {
                          // code here                            
                       });
```

With the Google contacts apis, we do not find any InsertRequest object.
We're using the ContactRequest class for Oauth integration.

```
 RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings(ApplicationName);
 string token = GetOauthAccessToken();
 OAuth2Parameters oauth2 = new OAuth2Parameters();
 oauth2.AccessToken = token;
 settings.OAuth2Parameters = oauth2;
 GetNextContactService = new ContactsRequest(settings);
```

Note: in the past, we were using the ContactService class with which we managed to batch inserts, but with this class we did not manage to attach an oauth token like in the code above.

old code:

```
PushContactService = new ContactsService("MigrationAsAService");
GOAuthRequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("cl", "theappname");
requestFactory.ConsumerKey = this.ConnectorSettings.ConsumerKey;
requestFactory.ConsumerSecret = this.ConnectorSettings.ConsumerSecret;
PushContactService.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

ContactsFeed feed = new ContactsFeed(
            new Uri(PushContactsURI),
            PushContactService
        );
feed.BatchData = new GDataBatchFeedData();
feed.BatchData.Type = GDataBatchOperationType.insert;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `ContactsService` class with OAuth2, by creating a [`GOAuth2RequestFactory`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/goauth2request.cs) and setting that as the service's request factory.